# Hide FloatingMenu caused by Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout

Slowly, I believe I am simply to dump to get this to work and hope
that somebody of you, can help me.

I am using the Android Design Support Library, AppCompat and support libarties:

```
compile "com.android.support:design:23.0.1"
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

All I wanted was a simple Toolbar, Tablayout and a ViewPager getting to work.
Like you can see in every other app, too.

But I am getting an annoying **FloatingMenu** on every activity that uses the 
app_theme.

[image]

How do I remove this FloatingMenu?

Cheers!

Douplicates:

[Remove Floating menu button from HTC one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495066/remove-floating-menu-button-from-htc-one) [noanswer]

Comment: Could you show your layout file?

Comment: Sure, but the FloatingMenu appears in every screen, not only there. Even on empty layouts, with only a RelativeLayout as parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot of people are facing this problem and its just not related to your code but to what kind of updates vendors have pushed.Try to confirm it by running your app on other devices too with different lollypop version.
Create a mainmenu.xml file with just one item (R.id.action_settings) 
and try to inflate it within your code and set the visibility to false afterwards. 
That will might solve the issue otherwise go into phone settings and button and then try to find out if there is any option to help you. It should be related to navigation or something i suppose.

> Edit

Setting your sdk version 14 or above seems to solve the issue. We went through many hit and trial and this one seems to work. I believe its a sort of bug in the design library.

Comment: people with htc complaining it more, see this one http://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-one/help/black-circle-dots-floating-button-t3052900

Comment: Adding the menu, inflating it and change the visibility of the item did not hide the FloatingMenu. Thanks nevertheless! Thing is, I need to remove it for every user that faces this problem.

Comment: just to ask, when you override the onCreateOptionMenu, did you tried to return false instead of true ?

Comment: I did, and it only hides the OptionMenu at the Toolbar, but not the one at the bottom.

Comment: what is your target sdk ? try to set your target sdk above 11. I also think that this three dots are more like a utility for switching between recent apps unlike earlier long pressing menu. try this also, Settings > Display > Buttons > Home and change "press and hold" from Google Now to Menu.

Comment: So much thanks! It was actually not 11, but with 13 as targetsdk you still get the floating menu, but it's gone with 14. Please change your answer, so I can accept it!

Comment: I have been facing with the same issue for a week or so. I did everything you(@Ankush Sharma) said but still the floating menu is coming in Samsung S6, kindly please help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like HTC issue try to override

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem settingsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        settingsItem.setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Wow really? Only HTC? But I can't find the id unfortunately. (Also in android R)

Comment: Try to add `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>` to the res/menu folder then add  `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);` before `MenuItem settingsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);` in code above.

Comment: Did nothing :( Any other ideas? This must be possible to archivie!